# CSS Image hover effect not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I tried to set hover effect on image but I wasn't able to do it properly.

Here is my code:

```
 .grid-image:hover {
     background: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/2rw7vxx.png") no-repeat scroll center top;}

.grid-image:hover img{
     opacity: 0.8 !important;}
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hxutuv8q/)

What I want is that little image be in the center of that snow leopard image on hover and is it possible to be in front of that snow leopard image? Snow leopard image should be less visible than this small image, is it possible to do it with only css?

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a pseudo element using `:after` and position it in the center of it's parent.

**CSS**

```
 .grid-image{
     display:block;
    height: 255px;
    width: 255px;
    opacity: 1;

    /*This is needed to allow absolute positioning of the :after pseudo-element inside*/
    position:relative; 
 }
.grid-image:hover:after{
    background: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/2rw7vxx.png") no-repeat center top; 

    /*This allows the pseudo-element to display properly*/
    display:block;
    content:'';

    /*This makes it appear at the correct size and position*/
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
```

**HTML** (same as what you have, but inline styles removed)

```
<article class="web-img">
    <a class="grid-image" title="project" href="#">
        <img class="post" width="225" height="225" alt="#" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/rwmidf.jpg"/>
    </a>
</article>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hxutuv8q/3/

Answer (score 0):

How much are you willing to change your HTML?  You could put your image as a background of your link, and the img tag as the check.

```
<article class="web-img">
  <a class="grid-image" title="project" href="www.google.com">
    <img class="post" width="32" height="32" alt="#" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2rw7vxx.png">
  </a>
</article>

<style type="text/css">
  .grid-image {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:225px;
    height:225px;
    background:url("http://i62.tinypic.com/rwmidf.jpg") red;
  }
  .grid-image img{
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-16px;
    margin-top:-16px;
  }
  .grid-image:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
  }
  .grid-image:hover img {
    opacity:1;
  }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxutuv8q/1/

Comment: I can't make changes to html because that code is dynamically generated, but thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Using an [`:after` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) we can place the tick background image above the `<img>` on hover.

- The tick is centered with `position: absolute`, `top \ right \ bottom \ left: 0;` and `margin: auto`.
- The tick is positioned relative to its parent `.grid-image` which has `position: relative`
- You can use the opacity and transitions to create a smooth hover opacity change

#### Example

```css
.grid-image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.grid-image:after {
  background: url("http://i58.tinypic.com/2rw7vxx.png") no-repeat;
  content: '';
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.grid-image:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.grid-image img {
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.grid-image:hover img {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<article class="web-img">
  <a class="grid-image" title="project" href="www.google.com">
    <img class="post" width="225" height="225" alt="#" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/rwmidf.jpg">
  </a>

</article>
```